# Accumulate list elements while adding a constant to each accumulation

Tags: numpy, cumsum

I'm accumulating values in a list so that a value is the sum of all previous values, using [np.cumsum()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
l=[4,2,1,3]
c = np.cumsum(l)
print(c)
```

> [4 6 7 10]

But I'd like to also add `1` to every computation, so that the result looks like:

> [4 7 9 13]

What's the simplest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
res = c + np.arange(len(c))
```